# Convert integer into year and months for whole column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am doing some data analysis and there is a column of Teacher Experience in my database in SQL server 2008. The teacher experience is entered in integer and decimal. For example-------8 means 8 years,0.5 means 5 months. Now I want to convert these values into years and months and output should be like this:
8 years and 0 months or 0 years and 5 months.

Is it possible to get results something like that? I searched online but couldn't get the idea on how it is implemented.

Comment: where do you want to convert those values?

Comment: through a sql query to a new named column like converted...

Comment: How would 8 years and 10 months be represented?

Comment: @GordonLinoff before converted you mean? it would be 8.11

Comment: How is the difference made between 8 years, one month and 8 years, 10 months? 8.1 == 8.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following:

`SELECT 
     CAST(CAST(TeacherExperience AS INT) AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' year(s) and ' + 
     CAST(PARSENAME(TeacherExperience, 1) AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' month(s)' AS Converted
 FROM 
     TABLE_NAME`

Comment: it is working fine but it is giving me output like this. For example the year is 7 then it outputs as 7 years and 7 months but it should display 7 years and 0 months

Comment: Could you please mention the exact datatype of your input column? This works fine if the input column ('TeacherExperience' in our case) has the datatype float and contrains values like 5.7, 2.3,11.9 ... etc. And would give a resultset containing a single column named ('Converted') containing the following results: 5 years and 7 months, 2 years and 3 months, 11 years and 9 months ... etc.